# Converting jquery element to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to give this button a div wrapper. How do I do that? And if I need to convert it to html to do this what is the most efficient way? Thanks

```
var button = ($('<button>', {
            "id": "jspsych-free-sort-done-btn",
            "class": "jspsych-free-sort",
            "html": "Done",
            "style": "text-align:center",
            "click": function() {
                var end_time = (new Date()).getTime();
                var rt = end_time - start_time;
                // gather data
                // get final position of all objects
                var final_locations = [];
                $('.jspsych-free-sort-draggable').each(function() {
                    final_locations.push({
                        "src": $(this).attr('src'),
                        "x": $(this).css('left'),
                        "y": $(this).css('top')
                    });
                });

                jsPsych.data.write({
                    "init_locations": JSON.stringify(init_locations),
                    "moves": JSON.stringify(moves),
                    "final_locations": JSON.stringify(final_locations),
                    "rt": rt
                });

                // advance to next part
                display_element.html("");
                jsPsych.finishTrial();
            }
        }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The reason I wanted the wrapper div was to center the button. But    button.wrap("<div style='text-align:center'> </div>"); doesn't seem to be working. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

> Description: Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.

```
button.wrap('<div></div>');
```

Comment: Won't `.wrap` return the original element, instead of the generated `div`? Consider using [`.wrapAll`](http://jqapi.com/#p=wrapAll).

Comment: Is that a problem?. OP just said he wanted to wrap the button in a div.

Comment: No benefit to `.wrapAll` here. OP's code above is quite explicitly creating just one element - so `.wrap` does the job.

Comment: Unless the OP wants to further manipulate the generated `div`. Which is something we don't know, as you pointed out.

Comment: @ZevSpitz wrapAll is for multiple elements, although it would work for one but no need for it

Comment: @charlietfl That is true, and it is the primary difference between `.wrap` and `.wrapAll`. But I think my previous comments still stand.